# How do I convert GAE TimeProperty to integer?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

In [this Python package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime) there is this code:

```
>>> dt = DateTime('Mar 9, 1997 13:45:00 US/Eastern')
>>> dt.timeTime()
857933100.0
```

I would use this package but there is a warning: "Unless you need to communicate with Zope 2 APIs, you're probably better off using Python's bult-in datetime module."

`TimeProperty` in GAE gives me something like this `02:37:31.797000` How do I convert it to a number as in the example so that I can add an integer to it and sort by the new value. I want to achieve some kind of weighed sort. Thanks.

**EDIT**

@Robert Kluin:

Thanks; this works:

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today().toordinal()
>>> today
734086
>>>
```

But I have a DateTime object that I am using in the query to sort; so this works:

```
    QUERY2 = Rep.all()
    QUERY2.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
    QUERY2.order("-mDATE")
    RESULTS2 = QUERY2.fetch(10)
```

But when I try this, it does not work:

```
    QUERY2 = Rep.all()
    QUERY2.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
    QUERY2.order("-(datetime.datetime.mDATE.toordinal())")
    RESULTS2 = QUERY2.fetch(10)
```

I get the error:

```
PropertyError: Invalid property name '(datetime.datetime.mDATE.toordinal())'
```

This is the value of `mDATE` as printed by the template:

```
mDATE = 2010-11-10 05:38:55.340000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) module.

```
import time
value = time.time()
```

Comment: Kluin: I realized that time `TimeProperty` and `DateTimeProperty` do not sort the same way. I need `DateTimeProperty`. I tried `mDATE = datetime.toordinal()` to convert `DateTime` object `mDATE` to integer but this does not work: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'toordinal'` I also tried `mDATE = datetime.datetime()` which also fails `TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found`. Is there a way to convert the DateTime property to number? Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to use a `datetime`, but you want to add some offset to it, look into `timedelta` (http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).  With a `timedetla` you can do things like:  `my_date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)`.  It sounds like when you tried `toordinal` you called it on the `datetime` module, not an instance.  Try: `datetime.datetime.today().toordinal()`.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.today().toordinal()` works but when I substitute my `mDATE` I get an error message. I updated the question if you want to take a look. Thanks again.

Comment: You will need to add another field to your model with the value you want to sort by.  Compute the integer version at save-time.