# Datetime and utctimetuple()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

In this code `mDATE0` for 3 items `a`, `b`, `z` is:

```
mUNIQUE: z | mDATE0: 2010-11-14 14:55:04.293000
mUNIQUE: b | mDATE0: 2010-11-14 14:53:34.824000
mUNIQUE: a | mDATE0: 2010-11-14 14:50:14.155000
```

But when I do

```
...
utc_tuple = rep.mDATE0.utctimetuple()
...
```

corresponding `utc_tuples` are:

```
utc_tuple: time.struct_time(tm_hour=14, tm_min=55)
utc_tuple: time.struct_time(tm_hour=14, tm_min=55)
utc_tuple: time.struct_time(tm_hour=14, tm_min=55)
```

In other words `min=55` for all items while `mDATE0` has

```
z --> min=55; 
b --> min=53; 
a --> min=50
```

What am I doing wrong? Please see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173245/working-datetime-objects-in-google-app-engine). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't code!  Please post short, complete example code to illustrate a problem.  Below is what I think you are trying to do, but without seeing your code, there is no way for anyone to point your bug.

```
from datetime import datetime
# build up some datetime objects.
z = datetime.strptime('2010-11-14 14:55:04.293000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
b = datetime.strptime('2010-11-14 14:53:34.824000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
a = datetime.strptime('2010-11-14 14:50:14.155000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
# display them
print 'z =',z
print 'b =',b
print 'a =',a
# print the minute
print 'z min =',z.utctimetuple().tm_min
print 'b min =',b.utctimetuple().tm_min
print 'a min =',a.utctimetuple().tm_min
# print the minute an easier way
print 'z min =',z.minute
print 'b min =',b.minute
print 'a min =',a.minute
```

#### Output:

```
z = 2010-11-14 14:55:04.293000
b = 2010-11-14 14:53:34.824000
a = 2010-11-14 14:50:14.155000
z min = 55
b min = 53
a min = 50
z min = 55
b min = 53
a min = 50
```